# JS next page as string hisotry.forward()

Tags: javascript, history, forward

I know JS has history.forward(), but I need to store it as a string.

I dont want to do any action, I want to have it as a string.

Comment: I don't think you can, the `history` API doesn't you give you the URL's as strings, you'll have to figure something out yourself, probably using localStorage or cookies

Comment: This would be a security violation, since a web site could then spy on your browser history.